# Why my wrapped meteor package isn't working?

Tags: meteor

I seek a little help to wrap a package for meteor. It has always been my weakness on this framework. I know it is not difficult, I read tutorials and some articles like :
https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/wrapping-npm-packages/
http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Packaging_existing_Libraries

However I get lost in export and stuff, and it is time to understand !

I tried to wrap this package :

https://github.com/fians/Waves

(I knew one day I was going to not find the package already made by someone on atmosphere :()
So I wanted to do the thnings right, following guidelines made by dandv. I forked the repo, add the meteor packages with the files : `export.js` and `package.js`. Following the example of [moment](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/meteor/export.js) As you can see here :

https://github.com/Voyag3r/Waves

Finally, in my app, I created the local package folder with the meteor command : `meteor create --package voyag3r:waves` I tried to called the `waves` variable, bit it is not defined. I tried with and without a capital letter. (like in the source code waves.js). No, I tried with `this.Waves` instead of just `Waves` in export.js, neither.
There is something I do not understand with namespace and visibility I think, and errors are not displaying useful information this time. Is there someone to explain to me ? Because I would like to do a lot of other packages !

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Glad to see that you read through those documents above, as they're quite helpful. However, I understand that it can be confusing to work through the details.  Hopefully, I can assist you.

I recently finished packaging up a couple of libraries for Meteor, so you should take a look at those repositories as examples:

- [jspdf:core](https://github.com/MeteorPackaging/jspdf-core-wrapper/)
- [jspdf:autotable](https://github.com/MeteorPackaging/jspdf-AutoTable-wrapper)

More specifically, take a look at the `jspdf:core` repository above and inspect the `meteor-pre.js` and `meteor-post.js` files for how to handle exporting variables:

- **meteor-pre.js**

  `var window = {};`
- **meteor-post.js**

  `jsPDF = window.jsPDF;`

Other important files include `package.js` and `package.json`, and of course `autopublish.json`, for integrating version updates with http://autopublish.meteor.com/, a fantastic tool written by [Luca Mussi @splendido](https://github.com/splendido).

Additionally, I would recommend that you review the [Official Meteor integration directly from 3rd party libraries](https://github.com/MeteorCommunity/discussions/issues/14) discussion and ask **@splendido** or **@dandv** for assistance with reserving the namespace for this library.

This process has gone through rapid change over the last few months, and although not perfect, it's improving steadily. I'm encouraged to see that, like me, you want to assist the Meteor ecosystem.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at this !